# Firebase FCM - Show notification timestamp on android via ADMIN SDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to display notification timestamp on android through Firebase Admin SDK ?

something like this :
[notif screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQvu4.jpg)

below is my payload which deliver notification successfully, but not able to show timestamp

```
       const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: msgTitle,
                body: msgBody,
            },
            data: {
                title: msgTitle,
                body: msgBody,
            },
            token: fcmToken,
            android : {
                priority: "HIGH",
                notification: {
                    title: msgTitle,
                    body: msgBody,
                    click_action: "HOME",
                    event_time: Moment().utc().format(),
                },
            }
        };
```

Comment: where are you generating this payload

Comment: if you want this at time of delivery, simply get the time in firebase service in your project using calendar and  show that in your notification

Comment: @aryanagarwal in my server. I send that payload through Firebase admin SDK.
Yes I want this at time of delivery. What you mean? I dont get it. sorry2. its on mobile side, server side or firebase console ?

Comment: Where you are getting the notification in android there you calculate the time and show it to user

Comment: @aryanagarwal ah I see. so it need to handle it on mobile app. is there a way to do this via admin sdk with some magic payload ?

Comment: you said you generate in server are you using php then simply compute there and attach that to payload

Comment: @aryanagarwal yes, in what field in payload ? I already dig the doc, but not found a clue. so I end up here. btw Im using node.js

Comment: you can add your own fields in data attribute of payload

Comment: @aryanagarwal then I need to handle it on mobile side right? so it can't be done via firebase admin sdk only ya?

Comment: yes you need to handle on mobile side  and also notification like you shared needs custom notification layout, if you use default layout it just shows message and title nothing else